# ls link count seems incorrect - how do I ensure I'm not deleting the inode contents?

Tags: bash, find, shell-script, hardlink

`ls -lai` on a file gives me a link count of 2:

```
16508 -rw-rw-rw- 2 ...
```

Then looking for all the filenames returns only one:

```
find "$dir" -inum 16508
```

This lists only the original file, not two. What's wrong?

Also, if I am deleting files with this code:

```
find "$dir" -type f -links +1 -exec rm '{}' \;
```

how do I ensure that I don't delete the last filename (given that the link count seems incorrect in the above example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was simply that the other filename resided outside of $dir. Running:

```
find / -inum 16508
```

found both filenames.